# A switch device was displayed in light Group

Tags: actions-on-google

[image - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av8MQ.png)

[image - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFF88.png)

[image - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhR2P.png)

I saw 6 lights and a switch in my Google Home App, after I do account linking. When I put them in a group called bedroom, the google Home App create "bedroom lights" group automatically, and the switch also include in "bedroom lights".

By the way, the switch have on-off and brightness capability. Is this the cause that the switch was include in "bedroom lights" group?

Comment: I guess it is due to the brightness capability

Comment: Your switch is called "Dimmer"? Do you think the name of it is making it assume the device group?